# Async SOQL Query - Insufficient_Access

Tags: soql, custom-permission, async-soql

I'm trying to learn Async Soql, and messing around with simple test scenarios. I've reached a block where I'm just trying to move the name of Account and create a new Custom Object with that name. I've tried a similar test between two custom objects, and got a similar error. I've tried searching profile security settings, and I couldn't find any way to enable these permissions.

> errorCode INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS
>
> Message: You don’t have permission to query this object Account with Async SOQL.

Comment: Async SOQL is available to select customers through a pilot program. For information on joining the pilot program, contact your Salesforce account executive. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_general_async_query.htm

Comment: I didn't realize it was for the pilot program, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @kurunve I think you should post that as an answer (that it's a pilot program).